# Image displayed on margin

Tags: html, css

I have a table with single row that contains some text (with new-line chars), e.g.:

```
<td id='line-numbers'>
<span class="number" id="1">1</span><br>
<span class="number" id="2">123</span><br>
<span class="number" id="3">31111</span><br>
</td>
```

From CSS perspective I added css: margin-right: 15px to line-numbers. 
Now I would like to insert images at the end of each row, e.g.:

```
<td id='line-numbers'>
<span class="number" id="1">1</span><img ...><br>
<span class="number" id="2">123</span><img ...><br>
<span class="number" id="3">31111</span><img ...><br>
```

where each image will be right-centered and displayed in 'margin' area on the right which height will match height of the font (width should be scaled to height). Please advise how to do it in the most effective way.

Thank you.

p.s. potentially I could introduce additional column on the right, but having no text (except line-break), I found it difficult to match (putting each line into separate table is currently not possible).

Comment: Just put the `<img>` inside the `<span>` and then `position` it `absolutely`.

Comment: Please create a code snippet so we'll be able to give you specific answer related to your HTML and CSS settings

Comment: Hi, I have created: https://jsfiddle.net/apd6Laj3/ with a template code. I would be really grateful if you could take a look and suggest changes to achieve the goal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not put `<img/>` within the `<span>`?

Like:

```
<td id='line-numbers'>
    <span class="number" id="1">
        1 <img src="" />
    </span>
</td>
```

Using CSS you can align the image to the right.
As you didn't provided any CSS I wasn't able to already implement it for you.

Comment: Hi, I have created: jsfiddle.net/apd6Laj3 with a template code. I would be really grateful if you could take a look and suggest changes to achieve the goal. Thank you!